# why _mm_extract_epi16 doesn't get expected result?

Tags: c, sse, intrinsics, sign-extension

I have found the bug in my program caused by misused SSE '_mm_extract_epi16' instruction, like below code:

```
#include <smmintrin.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int16_t test_input[8] = {-1, 2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8};
    __m128i v_input = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *)test_input);
    int32_t extract = (int32_t)(_mm_extract_epi16(v_input, 1));

   return 0;
}
```

If the extracted value is positive, then I get the right value 2. Oppositely I get the wrong value '65533'. Or I can use the below code get the right value.

```
#include <smmintrin.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int16_t test_input[8] = {-1, 2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8};
    __m128i v_input = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *)test_input);
   int16_t extract = (_mm_extract_epi16(v_input, 1));
   int32_t result = extract;

   return 0;
}
```

I don't know why it happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int _mm_extract_epi16 ( __m128i a, int imm)` matches the asm behaviour of the [`pextrw` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pextrw) of *zero-extending* into a 32-bit register.

Intel's intrinsics API uses `int` all over the place even when an unsigned type would be more appropriate.

If you want to do 16-bit *sign*-extension on the result,
**use `(int16_t)_mm_extract_epi16(v,1)`**.  Or assign it to an `int16_t` variable so the upper bytes of the result are ignored to start with.

unsigned `65533` = 2's complement `-3`.  This is normal.  (2<sup>16</sup> - 3 = 65533 = `0xfffd`)